# Probability of randomly selecting a number in the set ${2^n}$ from positive natural numbers?

Tags: probability, statistics, logarithms, approximation

From substituting up to the first $m$ natural numbers I found that the probability of an integer being in the set of integers $2^n$ is approximately $\frac{\ln(m)}{m\ln(2)}$. For example, for the first 10 natural numbers (1,2,3,...,10 where $m=10$), the probability of randomly selecting a integer in $2^n$ (there are three here – 2,4,8) is $\frac{3}{10}$ or 0.3. The approximation defined this as 0.332. However, I don't know the intuition behind this approximation (i.e. if it will work for all $m$) and I can't seem to find an exact form of this. I would be grateful for any help (btw, my main issue is finding an exact form of the problem).

Comment: The highest power of $2$ less than $m$ is $\lfloor \log_2m\rfloor$. so the probability randomly selecting a power of $2$ from $\{1,2, \cdots, m\}$ is $\frac {\lfloor \log_2m\rfloor+1}m$

Comment: Note:  In the above I assumed that $2^0=1$ was allowed as a power of $2$.  If you want to exclude that,. then remove the $+1$ from the numerator.

Comment: Brilliant! I see it now; thank you for that.

Comment: Btw, how would this work for even and odd numbers (i.e. the probability of selecting a power of 2 from $2,4,6,8,...$ – evens). Substituting $2m$ doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Just changes the denominator.  Now you are only selecting from $\frac 12 \times m$ cases (where $m$ is still the highest number in your list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{\ln(m)}{m\ln(2)} = \dfrac1m \log_2(m)$ is not a bad approximation, and is a lower bound, while $\dfrac1m \log_2(m+1)$ is a slightly better lower bound (tight when $n=2^k-1$ for some $k$)

$\dfrac1m \left(\log_2(m) +1\right)$ is an upper bound (tight when $n=2^k$ for some $k$) and is $\frac1m$ higher than your expression

As lulu says in the comments, the exact value is $\dfrac1m\left(\lfloor \log_2m\rfloor+1\right)$, shown as black below; your expression is shown in red and the upper bound in blue

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very insightful.